# How to add messages to a queue in different function and read it

Tags: python, django, multithreading, queue, python-3.6

I was making a app in which i had to implement socket. So insted to sending socket message from different functions I thought of add all messages to one queue and read it infinitly and send message from there.

But my problem here is when I add message in queue same is not received in reader.

Please any help or better idea for handling messages in welcomed.

My code is like this :-

```
from queue import Queue

from bot.core.utils import singleton


@singleton
class SocketFeedService:
    feed_queue = Queue()

    def add_message(self, username, message):
        message_dict = dict(user=username, message=message)
        print("Adding message", message_dict)
        SocketFeedService().feed_queue.put(message_dict)

    def reader(self):
        while True:
            message = SocketFeedService().feed_queue.get(block=False)
            print("feed message", message)
            SocketFeedService().feed_queue.task_done()
```

Singleton is implemented as follows :-

```
def singleton(class_):
    instances = {}

    def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in instances:
            instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[class_]

    return get_instance
```

And adding message like this :-

```
SocketFeedService().add_message(self.bot.user_instance.username,
                                                            log_string)
```

I tried reading in different thread as well but it did'nt work

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: I can't really understand what you are trying to do here. Apart from anything else, the singleton will only be single per process; a multi-process server environment will have multiple singletons. But your overall requirement is unclear.

Comment: Basically there is queue in SocketFeedService which I will read continuously and in my django app I want to push some messages in that queue. (There are multiple apps where i want to send this message, So i thought i add messages to single queue and then send it by reading it in an infinite loop)